# Xib to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I have `TableViewCell.xib` file where in each cell there can be summary of data like name, contact etc. Now if I touch the cell it will go to another `ViewController` where there will be details of that cell's data.(it does not matter what this `ViewController` shows). I want to go to another `ViewController` from this xib file's cell touch. how can I do that.

Edit:

CallHistoryTableViewCell.h

```
@interface CallHistoryTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    @property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *contactName;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *contactNumber;
@end
```

this class has CallHistoryTableViewCell.xib file.

CallHistoryVC.h

```
@interface CallHistoryVC : UIViewController
@end
```

CallHistoryVC.m

```
#import "CallHistoryVC.h"
#import "CallHistoryTableViewCell.h"

@interface CallHistoryVC ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,CallingViewControllerDelegate> {
AppDelegate *appDelegate;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<RecentCall> *sortedEventArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
//---add one contact---//
[self defaultViewSetting];
_tView.delegate = self;
_tView.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 75;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return _sortedEventArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CallHistoryTableViewCell";

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
DetailsOfHistory *storyViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsOfHistory"];
//[self presentViewController:storyViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; //  present it
[self.navigationController pushViewController:storyViewController animated:YES];// or push it

NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}
```

Everything works fine but in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` indexPath is not showing that means touch not working. By click on the cell I want to go to another viewcontroller in stroyboard.

Comment: Did you read the UITableView documentation? Go through this, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview?preferredLanguage=occ

Comment: Implement the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of UITableViewDelegate

Comment: Problem is there I could not link the xib to ViewController. is it possible to link xib to ViewController in storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

implement the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** as below

```
      - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    StoryViewController *storyViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryViewController"]; 
    [self presentViewController:storyViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; //  present it  
     //[self.navigationController pushViewController:storyViewController animated:YES];// or push it
            }
```

Set the cell id name as **CallHistoryTableViewCell** in your table view cell from your xib file.
Now in your **viewDidLoad** register your custom tableView cell

```
[self.tableView registerNib:@"CallHistoryTableViewCell" forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CallHistoryTableViewCell"];
```

and place the following code in your **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
CallHistoryTableViewCell *cell = (CallHistoryTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CallHistoryTableViewCell"]; 
return cell;
```

Comment: Can I use storyboard for creating that viewcontroller to move to that viewcontroller from xib? I am not clear

Comment: Actually when I click on TableViewCell which is in xib it is not working, that means in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if I print indexPath it is not working too.

Comment: However you have not yet mentioned it in your code that you share . By the way if my answer is helpful then you can give me a upvote . Thanks

Comment: But I have seen in another app that they used swipe gesture but also work click on cell. so my question is not incorrect though and I have to use that gesture too. so how can I do that

Comment: You can set another question for your issue didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working. it is not related to this question dude, by the way i think you are a newbie in iOS and also in stack overflow so you can not understand my help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register custom cell as xib do the following in viewDidLoad

```
[self.tableView registerNib:@"YourNibName" forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YourCellId"];
```

**yourXibname:**

[image]

YourCellid:

[image]

By the way, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: do like this.

```
yourCustomCell *cell = (yourCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourCellId"];
```